# query-replace bug?

Tags: query-replace, query-replace-regexp

When I run `query-replace*` commands if I type `?` I get this explanation of the function's options:

```
Type Space or ‘y’ to replace one match, Delete or ‘n’ to skip to next,
RET or ‘q’ to exit, Period to replace one match and exit,
Comma to replace but not move point immediately,
C-r to enter recursive edit (C-M-c to get out again),
C-w to delete match and recursive edit,
C-l to clear the screen, redisplay, and offer same replacement again,
! to replace all remaining matches in this buffer with no more questions,
^ to move point back to previous match,
u to undo previous replacement,
U to undo all replacements,
E to edit the replacement string.
In multi-buffer replacements type ‘Y’ to replace all remaining
matches in all remaining buffers with no more questions,
‘N’ to skip to the next buffer without replacing remaining matches
in the current buffer.
```

I often use `comma` to check the replacement. It happens that, some times, I get the error (e.g.):

```
match-substitute-replacement: Args out of range: #<buffer *scratch*>, 1667, 1679
```

The error doesn't happen if I type `y` (or `n`)

Try this:

```el
(query-replace ",.\\footnote{" ".\\footnote{" nil)
```

With the string ",.\footnote{" at the end of the buffer. To see the error "{" must be the last char in the buffer.

(I see often this bug because I use use "narrowing" a lot)

Is it a known bug?

My emacs version is GNU Emacs 26.3.

Comment: I can replicate in current versions of Emacs.  `M-x report-emacs-bug` if there's not an existing bug report for it.

Comment: When you report the bug, please provide a recipe to repro it that starts with `emacs -Q` (no init file).

Comment: @Drew I never reported a bug in my life! I did it now for the first time and I tried to do the best I can. I just posted the url of this issue.

Comment: Thanks for reporting the bug! But it's better if you include all relevant info in the bug thread itself, instead of just pointing here.

Comment: Ok, next time I'll do it better! I'll need to understand what "a recipe to repro it that starts with emacs -Q (no init file)" means!!!

Comment: It just means describe how someone else can see (reproduce) the bug, step by step. At each step say what you do, what you see, and what you expected to see instead. IOW, make it simple for someone else to do what you did, to see the bug.

Comment: It's the "emacs -Q..." part I don't understand.

Comment: `-Q` causes Emacs to start without any init files (site or user), so if you can reproduce the bug in such a session, it shows that the bug is really an Emacs bug, rather than an init file bug.

Comment: @NickD thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was indeed a bug. I believe it will be fixed in Emacs version 29.2.